# What can be done about the fact that Android automatically deletes corrupt SQLite files?

Tags: android, sqlite

When Android opens an SQLite file, and the file is corrupt, Android **deletes** the file.

As surprising as it may sound, this behavior is implemented clearly in the Android source code, leading to [consternation](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=756653) and to this [Android issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=10127).

Anyway, as app developers we just have to deal with it. What is the best strategy when opening an SQLite file?

- Corrupt files are actually often recoverable, so we can't afford to take any risk of losing one of those corrupt files.
- Creating a backup before opening is very time-costly, and would make the app startup really slow, so anything smarter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue has been fixed starting from API level 11. Now there exists an interface: **DatabaseErrorHandler** which you can implement to define your own **onCorruption()** method. At the opening of your database you can pass this DatabaseErrorHandler as a parameter to the constructor of **SQLiteOpenHelper**.

e.g.

```
public class MyDbErrorHandler implements DatabaseErrorHandler {
    @Override
    onCorruption(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // Back up the db or do some other stuff
    }
}

SQLiteOpenHelper dbHelper = new SQLiteOpenHelper(context, "MyDbName", null, 1,
                                                 new MyDbErrorHandler());

SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
```

---

**For Systems with an API level below 11 and for those who dont want to use this approach there are several alternatives.**

**1. Android data backup**

Android offers a backup service which automatically copys the application data to a remote 'cloud' storage. If a database gets corrupted or the application is reinstalled after factory reset. The application data can be restored from the remote data.

For further information see:  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html

**2. JDBC (sqldroid)**

One approach could be implementing your own database connector, either native JDBC or with the **[sqldroid library](http://code.google.com/p/sqldroid/)**. It is officially not supported by google and you cannot be sure whether it will be still available in future Android versions.

**3. Berkley DB Java Edition**

An interesting approach, also with a look to performance handling large data amounts, is the **[Berkley DB Java Edition](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/berkeleydb/overview/index-093405.html)**.

Here is a tutorial how to use it in Android: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17277_02/html/HOWTO-Android.html

**4. Customizing the android libraries**

Another more risky approach is to implement your own database class by copying or extending the SQLiteDatabase.java from the android source and reimplement or override the critical parts which are:

```
public static SQLiteDatabase openDatabase(String path, CursorFactory factory, int flags) {
    SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabase = null;
    try {
        // Open the database.
        sqliteDatabase = new SQLiteDatabase(path, factory, flags);
        if (SQLiteDebug.DEBUG_SQL_STATEMENTS) {
            sqliteDatabase.enableSqlTracing(path);
        }
        if (SQLiteDebug.DEBUG_SQL_TIME) {
            sqliteDatabase.enableSqlProfiling(path);
        }
    } catch (SQLiteDatabaseCorruptException e) {
        // Try to recover from this, if we can.
        // TODO: should we do this for other open failures?
        Log.e(TAG, "Deleting and re-creating corrupt database " + path, e);
        EventLog.writeEvent(EVENT_DB_CORRUPT, path);
        if (!path.equalsIgnoreCase(":memory")) {
            // delete is only for non-memory database files
            new File(path).delete();
        }
        sqliteDatabase = new SQLiteDatabase(path, factory, flags);
    }
    ActiveDatabases.getInstance().mActiveDatabases.add(
            new WeakReference<SQLiteDatabase>(sqliteDatabase));
    return sqliteDatabase;
}
```

and:

```
/* package */ void onCorruption() {
    Log.e(TAG, "Removing corrupt database: " + mPath);
    EventLog.writeEvent(EVENT_DB_CORRUPT, mPath);
    try {
        // Close the database (if we can), which will cause subsequent operations to fail.
        close();
    } finally {
        // Delete the corrupt file.  Don't re-create it now -- that would just confuse people
        // -- but the next time someone tries to open it, they can set it up from scratch.
        if (!mPath.equalsIgnoreCase(":memory")) {
            // delete is only for non-memory database files
            new File(mPath).delete();
        }
    }
}
```

The dangerous part about that is, that you also would have to reimplement the helper classes that access the SQLiteDatabase such as `SQLiteOpenHelper`. Since the `SQLiteDatabase` class uses factory methods you could face unexpected side effects.

Comment: Google should indeed fix this nihilist behavior, but I am afraid it is already too late. There ARE some phones around with this behavior, so we have to make sure we don't upset those phone's users.

Comment: Right! In this case I see only the approach with JDBC or to add the native sqlite source as jni library ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the sqldroid link, I did not know it. Actually some months ago I ported "SQLJet" to Android to circumvent a different issue. It is an open source Java SQLite client.

Comment: About BerkeleyDB: The app is for *.anki files, which are actually SQLite databases. That's the standard file format for several applications on PC/Mac/Linux/ios/Android, I can't change it.

Comment: I looked at sqldroid, and if I am not mistaken it is a JDBC wrapper over Android's SQLite implementation, so I guess it has the same issue?

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue and asked a question about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076119/android-database-corrupt-but-can-open-in-sqlite-manager-recoverable). I regularly backup my database to the SD-card, but I cannot recommend it. It seems as if a database that is copied from SD-cards used in newer Android phones is considered corrupt after the copy is completed on the older versions of SQLite that is still used on android 2.3.6.

If your database is small enough then I would recommend keeping a backup, but keep it on the internal memory. Unless it would anger your users, do not enable the "install to sd-card"-option, I believe it is correlated to the issue. After these precautions your database should be relatively safe.

About the slower start time: I do my backups in a background thread when the app is closed, this is the most likely time that the phone has to do some background work without troubling the user.

Comment: As I wrote (with more details) in my first comment to Michele, it can be 100MB or more. In this conditions, is it acceptable to backup in a background thread when the app is closed?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Then I would have to go with Dyonisos' answer even though it obviously have other drawbacks to stop using built in libraries (i.e. if they roll out a new and improved SQLiteDatabase-class you will have to release a new update to start using it).

Answer (score 1):

`Not for at opening every time`, But I think whenever our `database make a changes or upgrades` at that time `make copy of DB files for back-up` is the `one of the solutions`.

Also if possible to use `SQLite source and modifies` it and use it in our application with `JNI or Library`, then we can achieve it.

Thanks.

Comment: Indeed, forking Android's SQLite client could be an option. This is in the same spirit as using alternative Android SQLite client libraries SQLdroid or SQLJet (Dyonisos' answer).

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to this problem would be to replicate the DB entirely.

For example in the on Destroy method of your app. Copy the DB on every Destroy, when the main db is corrupted (and deleted by android) you can switch to the backup db.

Comment: My app is actually the open source AnkiDroid. The typical user has a dozen of *.anki files, each file can be 40 MB or even more. The total size can easily reach 100 MB, which takes time to backup. Is it still acceptable to do this in the "onDestroy" method?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul oh ok, thats alot, i think its safer to do some backup with in an background task. You have to find a balance between data safeness and time/battery consumption on the phone.

Comment: What do you refer to with "onDestroy method of your app" ? You mean the onDestroy method in an activity? That might mean a lot of backups (at an undetermined point in time - since the call for onDestroy may take some time). And as far as I know the Application class itself has no "onDestroy" method - does it?

Comment: thats right, onDestroy of your MainActivity with an Additional Timestamp in the SharedPreferences could work. So you Backup only ones a day or a week. OnStop would probably be better because apps can last very long in ram.

Comment: @Michele That's indeed an option :)