# Best alternative Android SQLite library?

Tags: android, sqlite

For [some reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764943/android-deletes-corrupt-sqlite-files-automatically) I want to avoid Android's official SQLite implementation.

There seem to be very few alternative, and they seem to be very new, not-tested-much libraries with few operations implemented.

I hope to not be too subjective, but here are the features I need:

- SQLite format
- Has SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
- Basic WHERE, with indexes
- Indexes are updated (I am not asking for new index creation)
- Open Source

Note: I recently ported [SQLJet](http://sqljet.com/) to Android, and I just saw the website of [SQLdroid](http://code.google.com/p/sqldroid/) (not sure what it does). I am surprised I can't find any fork of Android's SQLite, that could be acceptable as well.

Comment: Since SQLJet is either commercial or GPL it cold cause difficulties with licensing it for cs projects.

Comment: @Dyonisos GPL is perfect for us. Actually our whole project is GPL too.

Comment: Could someone please migrate this question to Software Recommendations? http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the [BerkeleyDB](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2191203)? (nice paper [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/berkeleydb/bdb-je-android-160932.pdf))

Or [H2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346236/h2-database-vs-sqlite-on-android)?

Comment: My app is for *.anki files, which are actually SQLite databases. That's the standard file format for several applications on PC/Mac/Linux/ios/Android, I can't change it.

Comment: @Nicolas Raoul Sorry, I didn't realize the file format compatibility is a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using [SQLiteJDBC](http://zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/index.html) in a desktop Java app for a couple of years now, with good results. I'm not sure how hard it would be to port to Android, but it includes a pure-java driver generated from the original SQLite sources (It uses [NestedVM](http://nestedvm.ibex.org/) which compiles everything to a MIPS instruction set, then generates a virtual machine in Java to execute the code - slow, but it works). Otherwise it also has native compiled binaries for several (desktop) platforms.

If you're not concerned about speed, or the size of your .apk (the .jar with just the NestedVM code is about 1.1MB), it might work for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [OrmLite](http://ormlite.com/sqlite_java_android_orm.shtml). I think it is convenient for you: lightweight, SQLite support with basic CRUD functionality. And it is easy to learn.

You can fork it from [Git](https://github.com/j256/ormlite-core)

> Object Relational Mapping Lite (ORM Lite) provides some lightweight functionality for persisting Java objects to SQL databases while avoiding the complexity and overhead of more standard ORM packages. It supports a number of SQL databases using JDBC and also supports Sqlite with native calls to Android OS database APIs