# SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase() delete file on error

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I use the code `SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY)`
to open a file. If the file is not a valid database file, the default behavior
is the file being deleted. Looks like the system is trying to delete a bad database 
file. What can I do to stop this?

I want my program to support API 7, so I can't add a `DatabaseErrorHandler`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a well-known issue. Interested readers may want to read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764943/what-can-be-done-about-the-fact-that-android-automatically-deletes-corrupt-sqlit) or [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=10127).